# Cypress does not recognice testcases

Tags: javascript, html, cypress

I use cypress to test Human Machine Interfaces (HMI) for programable logic controllers. The tests are pretty basic and mainly consist of click events and intercepting the network communication with route2.

When I run tests, cypress very often does not recognize one or more test cases and and states the error 'No commands where issued', despite the fact there surely were commands.

Is that a cypress issue?

Edit:

I didn't change the default configuration, just activated experimental network stubbing to use route2.

My testcases are very similar and look like the following:

```
it('example testcase', function(){
    //intercept network communication
    route2('POST','http://localhost/WriteTag', (req) => {
        req.reply()
        const request =JSON.parse(req.body)
        req.body = JSON.stringify(request)
        expect(req.body).to.contain('Some Value')
    })

    //Get button and click
    cy.get('#someID').click()
})
```

auto-generated code for the HMI:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class=" -moz-">
<head>
//couple of Scripts
</head>
<body id="proconweb_body">
   <div id="proconweb_mainarea" class="non-printable">
     <div id="box" style=[...]>
        </div><div id="StartLayoutbild" pweb-name="StartLayoutbild" pweb-type="gtiPicture" style=[...]>
          <div id="f4f64dbc-1fd6-4ae3-9e00-2e271e65580f" pweb-name="MainContainer" pweb-type="gtiContainer" style=[...]>
             <div class="carousel transition" style="white-space: nowrap; left: 0px;">        
               <div id="BildNr1" pweb-name="BildNr1" pweb-type="gtiPicture" style="left: 0px; top: 0px; position: relative; width: 1080px; height: 720px; padding: 0px; overflow: hidden; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); transform-origin: 0% 0% 0px; white-space: normal; margin-right: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px;" type="picture">

                <div id="fa1d2617-f2bf-4855-ade3-373b56c8518f" pweb-name="btLogVar1" pweb-type="gtiButton" pweb-style="common" style="left: 101px; top: 62px; position: absolute; width: 86px; height: 44px; box-sizing: border-box; overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap; cursor: pointer;" common="" state="" class="ie_workaround"><div><div style="position: relative;"><div style="width: 84px; height: 42px; overflow: hidden; position: relative; box-sizing: border-box; display: table-cell; text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;"><div>LogVar1</div></div></div></div></div><!--btLogVar1-->
                <div id="70db24ce-b219-4dec-b231-50305ad3a6f7" pweb-name="BooleanDigitLogVar1" pweb-type="gtiTagDisplay" style="left: 211px; top: 69px; position: absolute; width: 15px; height: 31px; overflow: hidden; font-family: Arial; font-size: 27px; font-weight: bold; font-style: normal; color: rgb(0, 0, 0);"><div spellcheck="false" class="textArea" style="width: 15px; max-width: 15px; height: 31px; text-align: right; padding-right: 0px; padding-top: 0px; white-space: pre;">0</div></div><!--BooleanDigitLogVar1-->

                //more elements with the same structure

                </div>
              </div>
            <!--MainContainer-->
          </div>
         </div>
       <div> class "non-printable pictureLoadArea"</div>
       <div class="printable"></div><input type="file" style="display: none;">
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Please add some details, hard to tell anything without. First try with your cypress config.

Comment: Sorry, you're right.